# Typescript simple reducers compose

Tags: typescript

I try to extend reducer functionality by composing them without the usage of extra `"compose"` utils (the simplified version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cd721)

Is there is a way how to perform such a pattern or I should try something different?

```
enum ACTIONS_I {
  CHANGE_VAL = 'CHANGE_VAL'
}

type ActionI = {type: ACTIONS_I.CHANGE_VAL, val: number}

type StateI = {
  val: number;
}

const initStateI = {val: 0}

function reducerI(state: StateI = initStateI, action: ActionI): StateI {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS_I.CHANGE_VAL:
      return { ...state, val: action.val };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////

enum ACTIONS_II {
  CHANGE_OTHER_VAL = 'CHANGE_OTHER_VAL'
}

type ActionII = { type: ACTIONS_II.CHANGE_OTHER_VAL, otherVal: string } | ActionI

type StateII = { otherVal: string } | StateI 

const initStateII = { ...initStateI, otherVal: '' }

function reducerII(state: StateII = initStateII, action: ActionII): StateII {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS_II.CHANGE_OTHER_VAL:
      return { ...state, otherVal: action.otherVal };
    default:
      return reducerI(state, action);
      // ^ ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this by changing two lines:

`type StateII = { otherVal: string } & StateI`

And just merge states

```
default:
      return { ...state, ...reducerI(state, action) };
```

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-d7u6w